# filesystem::directory_iterator pass to json

Tags: c++, json

I'm new at anything JSON.

I am trying to use this lib made by nlohmann:

https://github.com/nlohmann/json

I need to be able to loop over my folders, then loop over the items, and add them all to a JSON document.

```cpp
auto jComponents = nlohmann::json{ {"Components", nlohmann::json::array()} };
for (auto& p : fs::directory_iterator(path, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
    if (p.is_directory()) {
        auto jComponent = nlohmann::json::array();
        for (auto& sub : fs::directory_iterator(p, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
            if (sub.path().extension() == ".png")
                jComponent["image"] = sub.path();
            else if (sub.path().extension() == ".ini")
                jComponent["ini"] = sub.path();
        }
        jComponents.push_back(jComponent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes what i have does not work, it crashes when trying to add it

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and a detailed crash report.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jComponents` is not a json array, it is a json object with a property 'Components' whose value is an empty json array.  You are calling the `push_back` function on a json object without a property name.

I think what you want is:

```
jComponents["Components"].push_back(jComponent);
```

The signature of the `push_back` function:

```
// (1)
void push_back(basic_json&& val);
void push_back(const basic_json& val);

// (2)
void push_back(const typename object_t::value_type& val);

// (3)
void push_back(initializer_list_t init);
```

The first version assumes `this` is a json array;
The second version assumes `this` is a json object;
For the third, if `this` is a json object, the `init` must contain only two elements and the first one must be a string; otherwise, assumes `this` is a json array.

```
// NOTE: Not actually tested

json array = {1, 2, 3};
// [1, 2, 3]

array.push_back(4);
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.push_back({"a", 5}); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4, {a: 5}]


json object = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}};
// {a: 1, b: 2}

object.push_back(json::object_t::value_type("c", 3));
// {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

object.push_back({"d", 4});
// {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}

object.push_back(5);
// Throws
```